# YUI 3 Getting height of an element and apply it to another element

Tags: jquery, css, yui

I'm new to YUI and I'm finding it....strange compared to using jQuery for years. I can't seem to find out for the life of me on how to write something like this:

I'm trying to get the height of the div id #header and apply a ﻿margin-top  ﻿with the value being the #header height to a div id called #noHero.

So the html markup would end up being something like:

```
<header id="header" />
<div id="noHero" style="height: HEADER HEIGHT" />
```

Hopefully someone can help me here.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The gallery module [dimensions](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/dimensions) provides `totalHeight()`, so you can do this:

```
Y.one('#noHero').setStyle('margin-top', Y.one('#header').totalHeight()+'px')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Y.one('#noHero').setStyle('margin-top', Y.one('#header').get('region').height+'px')
```